# SVN: How to ignore a modified file on commit?

Tags: svn

I edited some files in svn, like this:

```
$svn st
M  a
M  b
...
```

Now, I want to commit my changes to svn, for some reason, I don't want to commit file `b`, is there any quick way or command to ignore the modified file `b`?

---

Finally, I use @yzucker Solution 1, cp, revert and commit. Changelists is too heavy, thank you all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alas, the commit many files with some annoying changes ignored problem.

Solution 1: copy, revert and commit

```
$cp b /tmp/
$svn revert b
$svn commit -m 'commit message'
$mv /tmp/b ./
```

Solution 2: copy, commit, reverse the effect of b, recommit b

```
$cp b /tmp/
$svn commit -m 'commit message'
$svn merge -c -{new revision} b
$svn commit b -m 'revert message for b'
$cp /tmp/b ./b
```

The second approach is less preferable since you introduce broken code in svn.

Comment: Nice idea, this should be a feature of Subversion itself. There should be a flag (let it call `-X`) which will exclude files from being commit.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [Changelist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.changelists) Feature of newer Subverion clients as shown in this short example session:

```
$ svn st
M       a
M       b

$ svn cl task1 a
$ svn cl task2 b

$ svn st
--- Changelist 'task1':
M       a
--- Changelist 'task2':
M       b

$ svn ci --cl task1 -m "checking in only task 1 stuff"
Sending        a
Committed revision 11.
```

Comment: What is the svn version?

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi "newer" in relation to the year of the answer: 2011. "old as the hills" in relation to the year of your question :-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an option to exclude only one file, and include all others that were changed. In you example, you could include only the files you want to commit by

```
svn co a -m "Only commit a"
```

which will then exclude b. See the [documentation of the command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.commit) with the examples at the end.

Another option could be to use [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.changelists), but that is more heavy ...

Comment: I use changelists for this purpose (though not through command line).

Comment: If there would be changelists to define files to explicitly exclude, that could be an option. But often, you have many files changed (not in the changelist), and only want only 1 *not* to commit ...

Answer (score 3):

If the file `b` has been already added to repository, it isn't possible to ignore it anymore. You have to delete this file, commit, recreate and set ignore property like this:

```
svn propset svn:ignore b .
```

The final dot means current folder.

If you want to ignore files only in this commit, type their names explicitly in commit command

```
svn co a c d
```

Where `a`, `c`, `d` are files you would like to commit.

Comment: Should the last command be `svn ci a c d`? This is a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On windows you can use GUI client [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and just choose only needed checkboxes.