# Exclude .git* files from git-svn dcommit

Tags: version-control, gitignore, git-svn, ignore

I've just started using `git-svn` to allow for more fine-grained branching and committing than I'd be able to use with the remote, controlled-by-another-company svn repo we're working in.

I've now set up my `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files for the branch, in my workspace, and I would prefer to be able to submit (and thus track) them in my local git repo. However, when `dcommit`ting my changes -/hardback to svn, those files must not be submitted back into the svn repo.
I can't just ignore the folder they're in either, however, because of course they're in the root of the workspace.

Does anyone have a solution? (apart from ignoring them in the git-svn branch, sym-/hardlinking them in from another location and adding them to a git repo there--it's overcomplicated and they're not in their corresponding branch anymore then, so I'd rather try to find a different solution in that case).

Comment: as a workaround for the `.gitignore` you could've used `.git/info/exclude`

Comment: @MykolaGurov is it possible to track changes in that file tho? Because if not, it has no real benefit for me...

Comment: no, not out of the box

Answer (score 0):

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22552349/6309), there is no easy solution.

For *common files*, you could use [`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620699/6309), but in your case, you want to *exclude* a file from being part of the svn repo.

The only workaround (more complex, I know) would be to do your `svn dcommit` from a dedicated branch where you delete those 2 files.
Then you switch back to your original Git branch and go on working, until the next `svn dcommit`.