# (TortoiseSVN) How to set files to ignor without removing them?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN on Windows 10 for my SVN repository. I have now changed some files and folders.

How can I set them to ignore, so that the files/folders are not removed (or changed) from the repository, but just no commit of them takes place?

All appraoches I have seen so far remove the files from the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TortoiseSVN Settings on the General page (the first page that opens up), there's a `Global ignore pattern` option that allows you it ignore certain folders or extensions:

[image: SVN Global Ignore Pattern]

If you want to ignore a specific file (or folder), right click the file, click `TortoiseSVN`, and click `Add to Ignore List`. You'll get options to ignore the file, any file with the file's extension, and a few others.  This property is committed to the repo for the folder.

Note: This option is only available if the file has not already been added to the repo.

If the file has already been added to the repo, there's no option to ignore changes. See [Ignore files which are already versioned](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-unversion.html)

You may also want to check out [Subversion: ignore modifications to a file locally on one client only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895548/subversion-ignore-modifications-to-a-file-locally-on-one-client-only). If this solves your problem, you may want to delete this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I want to ignore specific files and folders. Unfortuantely, the files and folders are already added to the repo. If I use the "add to Ignore List", they get removed from the repo, which I don't want.

Comment: Your second link with the approach "Move to Changelist"->"ignore-on-commit" worked for me but only for files. For folders it does not work (there is no such option for folders). Can this also be made for folders?